# Ubuntu Xenial 16.04: Getting rid of "modern"-styled applications

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04 introduced the new layout for some applications like gedit, eog and gnome-calculator, but also the new common file open dialog (which doesn't list the cwd directory anymore on the left pane).

Personally, I use Xubuntu with its Xfce, but I prefer the applications from above instead of mousepad and ristretto.

Do I have any options to get the old look back? AFAIK, the look is hard-coded into the applications, but maybe there's an active ppa with legacy-styled versions of them, or is this the point where I have to look at mate?

Old-styled gedit:

[image: old-styled gedit]

New-styled gedit:

[image: new-styled gedit]

Comment: A picture would really help here!

Answer (score 0):

GTK+ 3 has gone to massive change in its human interaction guidelines in order to allow for mobile appliances and desktops using similar interfaces. This brought you an interface like below. You can use MATE's application suite(`mate-desktop-environment`) instead of the GNOME's if you want older style. MATE supports GTK+3 along with GTK+ 2 with traditional window system human interaction style.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised that the mate applications are now in the official Ubuntu repository. The following commands installed the mate variants of gedit (pluma) and eog (eom)

```
sudo apt-get install pluma eom
sudo apt-get --purge remove gedit eog
#sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

The packages can be looked up in the package mate-desktop-environment (thx to @ErkinAlpGüney). The application galculator as a replacement for gnome-calculator didn't meet my expectations. Still open is the file open dialog, but I'm afraid that one is not easy to replace.

**Update**: still not happy with this solution: pluma seems to be based on an older version which opens the search dialog when pressing Ctrl+F instead of using the little overlay search box which allows to crawl through the results using Up and Down keys